# Closed subschemes and sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, noetherian

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme and $Y$ an integral closed subscheme of $X$. Why the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is indecomposable? (Indecomposable means that it cannot be expressed as a non-trivial product of sheaves)

Comment: The product of two rings has disconnected spectrum.

Comment: @Ahr how can the help me? Can you give me more details?

Comment: A product of rings is never integral. The spectrum of a product of rings is disconnected, so cannot be irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

the closed immersion $i:Y \hookrightarrow X$ corresponds to the structure sheaf exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{I}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow 0$$
The structure sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is hence given by a quotient of $\mathcal{O}_X$ by the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$. $Y$ being integral is equivalent to $Y$ being reduced and irreducible. $Y$ being integral means that vor every  affine open $\operatorname{Spec} A \subseteq Y$, $A$ is an integral domain. So "affine locally", this exact sequence above comes from taking a quotient by a prime ideal $\mathcal{I}$. This quotient is integral, so it cannot split into a product.

Comment: A MathJax tip: use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ - it looks better. I've made the upgrade for you this time.

Comment: @KReiser thank you, that is indeed much better.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Ahr, I added a line stating something similar to your comment. hope it is ok now!